# What is most efficient way to handle array object in react reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working with react reducer and came across one scenario and would like to know the better way to handle.
I have array of object list and i would like to modify one of the object from list in reducer. As per the standard we should not mutate the state.
I have the following example:

```
const state =
{
  items : [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'test1',
      'price': 10,
      'work': {
        'work1': 1
      }
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'test2',
      price: 20
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'test3',
      price: 30
    }
  ]
};
// here I would like to find item with id = 1 and modify that object with price = 40 and add new property into nested work property.
const test = state.items.map(item => {
  if (item.id ===1) {
    let newItem = {...item};
    newItem['price'] = 40;
    newItem['work'] = {...newItem['work'], 'work2': 2}
    return newItem;
  }
  return item;
})
```

I have checked the original state object and the new object after computation and found that state object is not being mutate.
I would like to know, is this the right approach to work with array of object list with reducer or is there any other standard way to do this.

I would like to thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior that the state doesn't change because when you use `Array.map` it copies every element instead of making a reference so the initial  object isn't changed after map and you have to:

```
const newItems = state.items.map(item => {
  if (item.id ===1) {
    let newItem = {...item};
    newItem['price'] = 40;
    newItem['work'] = {...newItem['work'], 'work2': 2}
    return newItem;
  }
  return item;
})
this.setState({items: newItems })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, as you create a copy of the object before doing the changes on that object. However, with ES6 you can go a bit further with destructuring to make it a bit cleaner. I would approach it the following way:

```
const test = state.items.map(item =>
    item.id === 1
        ? ({
            ...item,
            price = 40,
            work: {
              ...item.work,
              work2: 2
            }
        })
        : item
)
```